# How to store input given by user in html form in sql using php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my PHP code.

```
<html><head>
<title>login.php</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="login-style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<div class = "message">
<?php
define('DB_NAME','mydb');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','127.0.0.1');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
if($link){
    die('could not connect:'. mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);
if(!$db_selected){
    die('can\'t use'.DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
$value1 = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO Account (username,password) VALUES ('$value1','$value2')";

if(!mysql_query($sql))
{die('ERROR'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();
?>

<h1>Thank you for logging in </h1>
<form action = "form.html">
<p class ="submit">
<button type ="submit" >
GO TO FORM
</button>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to store the data in MySQL but when I run the html code (which i have connected to this php code using action =" name of this file"), no entry is done in database I created, can you tell me what is done wrong and help me to correct it?

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang = "en-US">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>Sign-In</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="style-sign.css">
<script type = "text/javascript">
function validateForm(){
var x = document.forms["forma"]["login"].value;
if(x == null || x == "")
{ alert("fill the field ");
  return false;
}
var y = document.forms["forma"]["password"].value;
if( y == null || y == "")
{
alert("fill the field");
return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div class="container">
<div class="login">
<h1>Login</h1>
<form  name = "forma" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action = "login.php">
<p>
<input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Username or Email">
</p>
<p>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login" >
</p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my html code which i have connected to this php file ,I am using xampp and using phpmyadmin , I am not getting any error and apache and mysql both are running

help me with this problem

Comment: Are you getting any error from sql?

Comment: 1. Mysql is depricated. 
2. Stackoverflow already has hundreds of similar (mostly same) questions.
3. Form action to html file?

Comment: You are using POST for name and password yet your form does not contain this textboxes

Comment: no I am not getting any error , it seems like i am unable to connect to mysql

Comment: @saurabh no i have made html file which has textbox , i am taking the value entered in the text box by user using post

Comment: there is no error at all?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Add your form code to the question.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Are you running this on a web server?

Comment: @jay yes i am running this on web server

Comment: Then there must be errors. If they are not being displayed you will have to look in your web server's error logs.

Comment: Since you're using HTML5 you do not need JS to validate the form fields. just add `required` to to the form elements.

Comment: @jay thanks for telling me  I didn't know that

Answer (score -1):

Change the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Account (username,password) VALUES ('$value1','$value2')";
```

To:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Account (username,password) VALUES ($value1,$value2)";
```

EDIT:
You do not have input fields setup for the username and password. So POST will not work.

Comment: Values have to be quoted going into the database if they are strings. Your syntax changes are incorrect. Instead of this you should be recommending [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score -1):

First you From needs an action and a method. 
Best woould be to rename the file to form.php

```
<form action = "form.php" method="POST">
```

in the result file ...

Connect to the database

```
$mysqli= @new mysqli('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
}
```

escape your value strings

```
$query= "INSERT INTO Account (username,password) VALUES ('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($value1)."','".$mysqli->real_escape_string($value2)."')"
```

Execute query

```
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
```

Verify results if any or check if an Error occured

```
if(!$result) {
    $ErrMessage  =  $mysqli->error . "\n";
    $mysqli->close();
    die( $ErrMessage) ;
}
```

Comment: In the html code you will need the 2 input fields "name" and "password"

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: @Jay Blanchard nice to see that you a negativ vote, but presenting a own answer. Execpt this, i wanted to show only a simple answer. In his code was nothing at all about security and the answer of user1423798 contained definitiv an error.

Comment: Not my negative vote - I just posted comments. It doesn't matter though, security should *always* be the first thing you think of, use and recommend. The OP hasn't posted enough code for me to speculate what the answer might be.